# Silent push not received (APNS) after fore quitting app

Tags: apple-push-notifications, voip, ios13

Do we have any alternative for chatting app becuase iOS silent push notifications are highly highly unreliable, for example

- if the app was terminated by the user they are not delivered at all
- if the battery power is <= 40%, the OS receives the push but often delays delivering it to the app for a few minutes
- if the batter pwer is >= 20, the OS receives the push but decides not to forward it to the app at all
- many other criteria affect whether the OS actually delivers the push to the app or not

We tried using Voip push to achieve smooth chatting behavior for apps not suspended state. But the problem is in iOS 13 its must to report incoming call on voip push arrival.

Do we have any other option or way around so that chatting apps like ours can work in background/suspended state (for short time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server has all the information you need to write the notification text, you can send regular push notifications that won't wake up your app.

There's no other way than using silent push notifications to run your app in background, but one alternative is to use [Notification Service app extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension). It won't wake up your app, only this app extension, but you'll be able to write code for it to modify the notification text before presenting it to the user

It's possible to share data between your app and this extension - by sharing the database or just some data using app groups or the keychain. Your app extension will only have 30 seconds to run, but that should be enough.

Silent push notifications are unreliable and should not be used to notify about a new message.

VoIP pushes are exclusive for reporting incoming calls.

Comment: @pespy thanks for your answer. Its the only solution for iOS 13 based apps. For the time being voip push can be used for other than call purposes only if the app is build  using earlier iOS version. But its temporary solution for apps to provide additional time for apps to update.

Comment: @AhadKhan yes, you can still use it if building with iOS 12 SDK (using Xcode 10). Starting on April 2020, though, you'll need to build with Xcode 11 to submit apps to the app store (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/).